# ngAnimate causing an error

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

```
Error: f.element._data is not a function t@http://localhost:3000/lib/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js:10 .enter/<@http://localhost:3000/lib/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js:14 Ad/this.$get</h.prototype.$digest@http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.min.js:101 Ad/this.$get</h.prototype.$apply@http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.min.js:103 f@http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.min.js:67 H@http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.min.js:71 od/</C.onreadystatechange@http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.min.js:72
```

That's the error that I'm getting. I'm not doing anything other than including the angular-animate file: `<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js"></script>` and including it in my app:

```
angular.module('mean', ['ngCookies', 'ngResource', 'ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap', 'mean.system', 'mean.articles', 'mgcrea.ngStrap', 'pascalprecht.translate']);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using angular-animate version **1.2.13** , but your angular.js version is older.

---

[This commit](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/b7e4e92014a5fe7a2d8c896703498090d88793ce) is part of angular.js version **1.2.13**:

> chore(jqLite): expose the **_data** lookup function to **angular.element**

```
!!! This is an undocumented "private" function !!!

var jqData = JQLite._data = function(node) {
   //jQuery always returns an object on cache miss
   return this.cache[node[this.expando]] || {};
 };
```

---

**Angular-animate:** [the line that uses the new 1.2.13 API](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.13/src/ngAnimate/animate.js#L674)

```
var elementEvents = angular.element._data(node);
```

---

Always make sure your angular.js version is IN SYNC with all angular modules.